# Encontrar um texto em sequencia em uma string

Tags: sql, string, oracle

Possuo essa String no oracle: 'Pedido vinculado com a Venda : 4575987/10'
e gostaria de retornar apenas o numero do pedido nesse caso o 4575987/10.
Até o momento o maximo que consegui é passando um valor fixo, mas inves de um numero fixo gostaria de passar A FRAÇÃO DO TEXTO ('Pedido vinculado com a Venda :')

segue query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(LTRIM('Pedido vinculado com a Venda : 57994/73'), 32)) FROM dual;
```

Dessa forma funciona, mas existem casos que uma informação anterior é posta nessa mesma string e por isso pode não trazer o numero do pedido.
Segue exemplos que podem ocorrer:

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(LTRIM('Volume: 235 rolos Pedido vinculado com a Venda : 53160/73'), 32)) FROM dual;

  SELECT TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(LTRIM('ENVIAR SOMENTE ROLOS DE FABRICAÇÃO RECENTE E PRIORITARIAMENTE ROLOS COM 55 M2. Pedido vinculado com a Venda : 55814/73'), 32)) FROM dual;
```

esses exemplos que passei fixos estão dentro de um campo de obs de uma tabela, e por isso podem variar, mas o texto 'Pedido vinculado com a Venda :' pode ser encontrado dentro deles, se eu conseguisse a partir desse texto buscar os proximos 8 caracteres já seria ótimo!

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo deste outro caso?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, consegui resolver o problema aqui, fazendo conforme abaixo eu sempre terei o valor do pedido(neste caso se o pedido conter esse mesmo tam de numeros), ou eu posso ocultar o valor do substr então ele me trará o numero completo:

```
SELECT LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTR('ENVIAR SOMENTE ROLOS DE FABRICAÇÃO RECENTE E PRIORITARIAMENTE ROLOS COM 55 M2.
Pedido vinculado com a Venda : 55814/73',  INSTR('ENVIAR SOMENTE ROLOS DE 
FABRICAÇÃO RECENTE E PRIORITARIAMENTE ROLOS COM 55 M2.
Pedido vinculado com a Venda : 55814/73', ': ', -1, 1), 10), ':')) FROM DUAL;
```

Assim posso passar qualquer texto que ele irá localizar sempre a partir do ultimo : com o argumento -1 do instr.

Comment: Se possível altere o modelo para ter o pedido em um campo separado.